# Error when trying to apply Lambda and Alpha arguments when using ml_linear_regression in Spark (using R)

Tags: r, apache-spark, lambda, linear-regression, alpha

I am trying to run a regression with alpha = 1 and lambda = 0, however I keep getting an error. 
I will write down the whole code and packages.

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

# Install the `glmnet` package in your user library

if(system("hostname", intern=TRUE) == "gbef4001.hpc.wvu.edu"){
  Sys.setenv(SPARK_HOME = "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/")
  sc <- spark_connect(
    master = "yarn-client",
    source = "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/lib/spark/bin/spark-submit",
    version="2.4.0")
} else {
  sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
}
path.data <- paste("file://", getwd(), "/prostate.csv", sep = "")
```

Then I turn the data into a dataframe in both R and then in Spark

```
prostate_df <- read.csv(path.data)

prostate_sdf <- sdf_copy_to(sc, prostate_df, "prostate_sdf", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Then I try to run an regression using the lambda and alpha arguments

```
prostate_sdf %>% ml_linear_regression(lpsa ~ lcavol + lweight + age + lbph + svi + lcp + gleason + pgg45, alpha=1, lambda=0)
```

But I keep getting the error below

```
Error: 2 components of `...` were not used. We detected these problematic arguments: * `alpha` * `lambda` Did you misspecify an argument?
```

Any idea how to remedy this? thanks

Comment: From reading the help file `?ml_linear_regression`, I have the suspicion that alpha is set with elastic_net_param, and lambda with the reg_param arguments. That is, alpha and lambda do not appear to be the names of the arguments that you seek to use.

Comment: Aha, I think you are right